# Web Audio API, periodic wave

Tags: javascript, web-audio, фурье

**Как создать волну нужной формы**, как работает функция создания, причем здесь преобразование Фурье, как влияет параметр нормализации(включенный и выключенный)?

Доки:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/createPeriodicWave
- https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#dom-baseaudiocontext-createperiodicwave
- https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#dom-periodicwaveoptions-real

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На примере функции по упомянутой ссылке это работает так:

- Генерируется и суммируется набор синусоид, частота каждой из которых в (2, 3, 4, ...) - в целое число раз больше "оcновной частотой".

  Эти синусоиды называются гармониками основной частоты, а то, во сколько раз её частота больше основной частоты, называют её порядковым номером.

  Как результат, всё вместе (суммарный сигнал) воспринимается на слух, как звук, соответствующий основной частоте, только обогащённый разной тембровой окраской.
- В массивы **real** и **imag** помещается информация о номерах гармоник, которые будут добавлены в выходной сигнал.

  Таким образом - номера ячеек массивов соответствуют номерам гармоник.

  Разница между этими массивами в том, что пиковые значения амплитуд гармоник в массиве **real** вычисляются с помощью косинуса номеров гармоник, а в массиве **imag** - с помощью синуса.

  Для первого знакомства можно поместить данные только в один из двух массивов, на пример, **imag**.

В примере ниже для наглядности изменения тембровой окраски данные массивов обновляются **5 раз в секунду**, благодаря чему мы слышим непрерывный тембровый перелив одной и той же основной частоты:

```html
<button onclick="mystart()"> старт </button> 
<button onclick="osc.stop(); clearInterval(b); ac.close()"> стоп </button>
<script>
var numCoeffs = 15; // максимальный порядковый номер гармоник
function mystart(){
ac = new AudioContext();
osc = ac.createOscillator();
osc.frequency.value = 100; // основная частота, т.е., гармоника №1
osc.connect(ac.destination);
b = setInterval(function(){
var real = new Float32Array(numCoeffs);
var imag = new Float32Array(numCoeffs);
var i = 0;
while(i < numCoeffs){
 var myrand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 2;
 i += myrand;
 imag[i] = 1;
}
var wave = ac.createPeriodicWave(real, imag, {disableNormalization: false}); // нормализация включена
osc.setPeriodicWave(wave);
}, 200);
osc.start();
}
</script>
```

Нормализация желательно должна быть включённой, иначе в результате суммирования большого количества гармоник размах сигнала может выйти за пределы крайних значений, и тогда не избежать неприятных искажений. А [Жан Батист Фурье](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%B5,_%D0%96%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82_%D0%96%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%84) имеет к этому отношение, как разработчик алгоритма обратного процесса - [разложение](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Introduction) сложного звукового сигнала на синусоидальнае составляющие (гармоники). К сожалению, Web Audio API пока не позволяет качественно воспроизводить гармоники с частотами, близкими к нижнему и верхнему пределам слышимого диапазона.

Comment: Извините, qwabra, но я не могу принять Ваше изменение кода. Благодаря пустым комментарием и комментарием, занимающим отдельную строку, общее количество строк JS-кода увеличилось больше, чем в 2 раза. Комментарии со слешем и звёздочкой используют для комментирования целого блока кода, для одной строки достаточно двух слешей в правой части строки с кодом.

Comment: Ещё если после этого изменения в такой же последовательности всё пместить на странице, то работать не будет, а выдаст ошибку Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null. И нежелательно, чтобы имена ID элементов совпадали с именами событий Web Audio API. Поэтому я пока код вернул по-старому.